# Можно ли вернуть Windows 10 обратно, после обновление на Windows 11?

Tags: windows, пк

Стало доступно обновиться бесплатно до Windows 11, но боюсь, что больше не вернусь обратно на Windows 10.

Как мне потом обратно сделать бекап до Windows 10, если вдруг что-то пойдёт не так. Без потери файлов конечно бы.

Comment: Можно [откатиться штатными средствами](https://www.neowin.net/news/not-satisfied-with-windows-11-heres-how-you-can-rollback-to-windows-10/). Помнится, после апгрейда на Win10 тоже месяц хранился бекап предыдущей системы для возможного отката.

Comment: ^ Или можно воспользоваться чем то вроде Acronis True Image или каким то из аналогов вроде AOMEI Backupper. Правда сначала рекомендую покурить ютуб про то как они работают, и на бэкап и на восстановление. И да, я себе на 11 обновляться пробовал, НЕ рекомендую, однако... Оно еще СЛИШКОМ сырое, и вряд ли станет юзабельно до осени/зимы... А если очень хочется пощупать, лучше сделай https://www.google.com/search?q=windows+11+virtualbox

Comment: лучше vmware player, virtualbox уж больно глючный

Comment: @PavelGridin, можно подробнее? А то я на VBox с v1.6.5 и чё-то не сильно замечал глюки.